# Error seemingly generated by AnyLogic itself: "Duplicate local variable self"

Tags: anylogic

I developed a model that simulates a dice game where each player represents a workstation of a factory. I built the model once it and worked/ran fine with no issues. All of a sudden, without any changes, it presented the below explained error. When I check the error in the "Main.java" it shows a code from internal Anylogic settings, and not a configuration I made myself or any code I wrote myself.

As I could not identify the issue, I went back one version (which was still working) and added again step by step the changes from the newest version. Again, the model was built with no errors and ran fine. I then did not access this model for a few days, and when I did, the same error from before appeared. I am not able to identify the problem, as it is, as mentioned, "not my own modeling."

**Error: Duplicate local variable self. Location: Dice_Game_DtC/Main - Agent Type**

The model is run mostly by some events. Basically, AnyLogic defines a variable "self" for each event, which results later in "Main.java" in this duplicate error.

See the code example from the events "Define_Downs" and "Pay_Costs" as well as "Check_Invests" (as per image). The remaining events, such as "Sell_Products" and "Initial_WIP," don't have this problem. [image][image][image]

```
 if ( _e == Pay_Costs ) {
      EventTimeout self = _e;

//My code below
Fixed_Costs_Round=Fixed_Cap_Cost;
Fixed_Cap_Costs_Payed.add(Fixed_Costs_Round);
Total_Fixed_Costs=Total_Fixed_Costs+Fixed_Costs_Round;

Total_Inv_Round=Total_WIP+Available_Finished_Prd;
Total_Inv_per_Round.add(Total_Inv_Round);
Invent_Cost_Round= Total_Inv_Round/Num_Players;
Invent_Cost_per_Round.add(Invent_Cost_Round);
Total_Invent_Costs=Total_Invent_Costs+Invent_Cost_Round 
//End of my code

;
      return;
    }
    if ( _e == Define_Downs ) {
      EventTimeout self = _e;

//My code below

//1. Set NO downs always for PLayer 1
for (int i = 1; i <= Num_ROUNDS; i ++){
    Downtimes_P1.add(i,0);
    Downtimes_ME_P1.add(i,0);
    Downtimes_MA_P1.add(i,0);
    Downtimes_HU_P1.add(i,0);};

//2. Set NO downs at rounds 1 and 2 for all players
for (int i = 1; i < Num_Players; i ++){ //start at one because index 0 is P1, which was already set
    Downtimes_Datasets.get(i).add(1,0);
    Downtimes_Datasets.get(i).add(2,0);
    MA_Downs.get(i).add(1,0);
    MA_Downs.get(i).add(2,0);
    HU_Downs.get(i).add(1,0);
    HU_Downs.get(i).add(2,0);
    ME_Downs.get(i).add(1,0);
    ME_Downs.get(i).add(2,0);
    };

//3. Define for all players (except 1) and all rounds (except 1 and 2) the downs - for every 2 rounds
for (int i = 1; i < Num_Players; i ++){ //starting at one to ignore player 1 (that has index 0)
    for (int y = 3; y < Num_ROUNDS; y +=2){ //Y=round
        //first defining down per partner (machne, method, human)
        double down_value_ma=uniform(0,1);//MACHINE
        if (down_value_ma<DWT_Machine_Prob) down_value_ma =1; else down_value_ma =0; 
        MA_Downs.get(i).add(y,down_value_ma);
        MA_Downs.get(i).add(y+1,down_value_ma);
        
        double down_value_me=uniform(0,1);//METHOD
        if (down_value_me<DWT_Method_Prob) down_value_me =1; else down_value_me =0;
        ME_Downs.get(i).add(y,down_value_me);
        ME_Downs.get(i).add(y+1,down_value_me);
        
        double down_value_hu=uniform(0,1);//HUMAN
        if (down_value_hu<DWT_Human_Prob) down_value_hu =1; else down_value_hu =0;
        if (y>=HeadC_Inv_Round) down_value_hu=0;//if such round got HP investment, set DWT as 0 anyway
        HU_Downs.get(i).add(y,down_value_hu);
        if (y+1==HeadC_Inv_Round) HU_Downs.get(i).add(y+1,0) ; else HU_Downs.get(i).add(y+1,down_value_hu);//if the second round is the investment one, already set 0 for it
        
        //if any partner is down then station is down
        int down_value;
        if (down_value_ma==1||down_value_me==1||down_value_hu==1) down_value=1; else down_value=0;
        
        Downtimes_Datasets.get(i).add(y,down_value);
        Downtimes_Datasets.get(i).add(y+1,down_value);};}
//End of my code
 
;
      return;
    }
```

[image]

[image][image]

[image]

I tried to remodel the model and achieved success, but only for a while. The weird error all of a sudden appeared again later.

I would appreciate any support on how to fix that. Many thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to unclean coding.

Just looking at your screenshots, I can see ";" where there should be none:
[image]

and I see lines without ";" at the end that should have some:
[image]

This may "trip up" Java upon re-compiling...

Maybe carefully review ALL of your code and clean it up